# Problem when a flexbox container is placed inside a grid cell

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have a grid with couple of columns and some gap between them

```
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 3px;
}
```

Then I want to place an `input` to both cells. But this input has to be styled with some border and so on. It's convenient for me to wrap it in a flex container:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <input type="text">
</div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;

  border: 1px solid #cc0384;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;

  > input {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

And then I just want to place such inputs into the cells of a grid.

```
<div class="my-grid">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect that there will be a couple of inputs which are separated by gap. But suddenly they are intersected with each other. It seems that an internal input takes the whole width of grid cell and flex-box containers are spilled over the borders of grid cell. What is the reason and how to fix that?

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DonTomato/m7ox8whb/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `padding` is causing this problem. You say `width: 100%` and `padding: 5px` so the overall width is `100% + 2 * 5px = 100% + 10px` (5px on the left and right).
To avoid that the width is increasing over 100%, you can say `box-sizing: border-box`. So your `flex-container` will have a overall width of 100%, but the `padding` is already calculated.

You can use `border-box` to prevent that `borders` and `paddings` will "spread" above your configured size (`width` and `height`).

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;

  border: 1px solid #cc0384;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here are some helpful links:

[CSS Box Sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

[box-sizing CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

**Edit:**
Added a code example.

```css
.parent{    
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
}

.is-border-box{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fullsized-child{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fullsized-child">Without box-sizing: border-box. The parent size is stretched from 200x200px to 240x240px.</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent is-border-box">
    <div class="fullsized-child">Without box-sizing: border-box.
    The parent size is remains 200x200px.
    </div>
</div>
```